# Как по очереди анимировать Views

Tags: java, android

У меня на странице несколько `View`. Нужно чтобы каждый анимировался после предыдущей.

1) Думал для каждой анимации делать задержки, но мне кажется этот вариант не правильный.

2) У каждой анимации в `Listener` в методе `onAnimationEnd()`, вызываю след анимацию. Анимации беру из `xml`. В этом решении заметил то, что следующая анимация не сразу срабатывает. Да и у меня `View` 8-10 штук и для каждого реализовывать `Listener`, тоже как-то не чисто получается.

Здесь всего 3 `вьюшки`, а занимает столько места:

```
mLogo.startAnimation(zoomInAnim);
    zoomInAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mPackage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPackageBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPackage.startAnimation(slideUpAnim);
            mPackageBack.startAnimation(slideUpAnim);
            slideUpAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mImage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mImage1.startAnimation(slideUpBounceAnim);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

Вопрос: Как вы комбинируете `Views` и очередь анимации, может есть другие решения, о котором я не знаю?

Comment: Можно попробовать создать вспомогательный класс который имплементит `Animation.AnimationListener`, переопределить его методы и писать что - то типо `zoomInAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationHelper(yourArgs))`, передавая в его конструктор все нужные вьюхи. Нет под рукой IDE чтобы написать и проверить, поэтому в комментах.

Comment: Проверяйте в `onAnimationEnd` какая из анимаций закончилась и запускайте следующую. Например, по списку ваших `view`. Или, в случае со списком, задайте глобальную переменную, плюсуйте ее каждый раз на окончании и анимируйте следующий элемент списка

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

Создаем массив View, к примеру TextView. В каждом, соответственно, имеется слово.

```
TextView arrayTextView[] = {tvW1, tvW2, tvW3, tvW4, tvW5, tvW6, tvW7, tvW8, tvW9, tvW10};
```

Пишем метод

```
private void animate(final TextView tv, int delta) {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //будем увеличивать размер букв
            tv.setTextSize(40f);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, delta * 400);
}
```

Перебираем массив в цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayTextView.length; i++) {
    animate(arrayTextView[i], i);
}
```

Итого. Каждые 400 ms в очередном TextView шрифт становится крупнее.